# Unpacking of initramfs is very slow

Tags: boot, time, initramfs

I am trying to improve the kernel boot time of my device and I would like some help. I am using **OMAPL138** with kernel version **2.6.37** and it takes about 50 seconds until the boot process is finished, and I think it is a long time. Below is the image of some stages of the boot process. As you can see, there is a delay of 19 seconds until the message **EMAC: MII PHY CONFIGURED** shows up and I think this is the main problem of my boot time.

[image: kernel boot process]

After some tests I discovered that this delay is during the unpacking of the **initramfs.cpio.lzma** . I discovered it by printing some messages in the **initramfs.c** file, and this delay happens in the *while* loop inside the **unpack_to_rootfs** function. The initramfs.cpio.lzma has 5.3MB and the total kernel image (uImage) has 7.3MB .

My question is: Am I doing something wrong or the only way to improve this is by reducing the size of my kernel? Maybe some of you had to deal with this problem before so I would like some suggestions on how to proceed to improve my boot time. Thank you very much.

Comment: if copying would be faster than decompression, you could use GZIP's level 0, which just stores without compressing

Comment: Thank you Janus, I will try this and post the result here

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not a CPU bottleneck but slow flash media access time? Found this thread below on the TI forums talking about flash throughput being limited to 0.6 MB/sec.
[OMAP-L138 EVM SPI Flash read performance and boot time](http://e2e.ti.com/support/dsp/omap_applications_processors/f/42/t/41068)

For a test (as Janus suggested), see if you can compress a kernel image and/or the initramfs with `gzip -0` if possible.  Or might be simpler to (on another workstation), get a copy of your **initramfs.cpio.lzma** file, uncompress it to **initramfs.cpio**, then recompress with `lzma -0`.  Overwrite the new recompressed file back to your flash media.  I would expect the file should be slightly larger. If boots faster, then probably CPU was a bottleneck. If it boots slower, then likely IO was the bottleneck.

Maybe even repeat the test with `lzma -9`, but beware can require lots of memory for both compression and decompression.

Here's an excerpt from the lzma (v5.07) man page:

> ```
>      On the same hardware, the decompression speed is approximately
>      a constant number of bytes of compressed data per second.   In
>      other words, the better the compression, the faster the decom-
>      pression will usually be.  This also means that the amount  of
>      uncompressed output produced per second can vary a lot.
>
>      The following table summarises the features of the presets:
>
>             Preset   DictSize   CompCPU   CompMem   DecMem
>               -0     256 KiB       0        3 MiB    1 MiB
>               -1       1 MiB       1        9 MiB    2 MiB
>               -2       2 MiB       2       17 MiB    3 MiB
>               -3       4 MiB       3       32 MiB    5 MiB
>               -4       4 MiB       4       48 MiB    5 MiB
>               -5       8 MiB       5       94 MiB    9 MiB
>               -6       8 MiB       6       94 MiB    9 MiB
>               -7      16 MiB       6      186 MiB   17 MiB
>               -8      32 MiB       6      370 MiB   33 MiB
>               -9      64 MiB       6      674 MiB   65 MiB
> ```

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I did not see this thread on TI. I will follow your instructions and post results here.

Comment: Joshua, I compressed using lzma -0 and now it boots slower. I was using lzma -9 before and the intiramfs.cpio.lzma size was 5.3MB, now with lzma -0 the size is 7.1MB and it takes a little more time to boot. So do you think this is a slow flash media access time?

Comment: Per the man page, it says that lzma decompression is actually faster with higher compression levels.  So not able to make a definite conclusion whether it's CPU or media IO.  Just based on the TI forum thread above, it seems that the media access might be done 1 byte at a time, so with 50 MHz clock on the media interface, this would explain a max 0.6 MB/sec transfer from flash memory to system memory.  Here's a page with possible ways to optimize that transfer:  http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/All_This_For_1_Second_Boot#Make_NOR_to_DDR_Copy_Faster

Answer (score 0):

If the IO speed is not the bottleneck, then another option is to use LZ4 compression, which gives files a bit bigger than gzip, but decompression is extremely fast.

The kernel config option to compress the kernel with this is CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4=y.

http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/lcjpcojp13_klee.pdf